# Why, in RelaxedPropertyResolver, getProperty and getSubProperties behave differently?

Tags: spring-boot

Two similar methods don't behave similarly:

- RelaxedPropertyResolver#getProperty calls PropertySourcesPropertyResolver#getProperty where the first PropertySource having the value for the key wins
- RelaxedPropertyResolver#getSubProperties calls PropertySourceUtils#getSubProperties where the last PropertySource having the value for a key in the sub tree wins

Obviously PropertySources are sorted the most important/specific first, the least important last. So when I call RelaxedPropertyResolver#getSubProperties I get default values instead of customized ones.

Is there a reason? Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it's a bug. We have [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1259) open for it and it's currently targeted at 1.1.5.